# Maven error while assembling hadoop in stand alone mode

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new to hadoop and maven. I will like to compile the hadoop 2.0.3 from the source and install it. I am following instructions from
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

So far, i have managed to download hadoop source code and from the source directory issued "mvn clean install -Pnative"
Next i tried to execute mvn assembly:assembly, but i get following error:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.3:assembly (default-cli) on project hadoop-main: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found. -> [Help 1]

Please help so that i can move forward.

Also, the above mentioned install link, does not mention what should be the value of "$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME"

Comment: I got the same problem and cannot solve it. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I compiled 1.0.4 just as an academic exercise. Not sure if it will be valid for 2.0.3

This should be done (on Ubuntu) before you start compilation to make sure that all needed stuff is there:

```
sudo apt-get -y install maven build-essential protobuf-compiler autoconf automake libtool cmake zlib1g-dev pkg-config libssl-dev
```

I did not had subversion so I did this too:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

After that I checked out the code:

```
svn checkout http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.0.4/ hadoop-common-1.0.4
```

Then went to newly created folder “hadoop-common-1.0.4″ and gave command:

```
ant clean package
```

You can refer to my blog for the whole story:
http://hadoopmagic.wordpress.com/